# Displaying PDF in popup causes window.close to be true

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I displayed a PDF in a popup window (IE11), tried to close the popup using the child window object but found that its already closed but the pdf if still open. This makes it evident that Acrobat is still working. Is is possible to close this from the browser using java-script? I tried embedding the pdf in iframe but its still not working..

Is there a work around for this using JavaScript?

Comment: Not all browsers support viewing PDF within browser window, let alone inside a popup. So to be consistent i suggest you give a link with target blank. if browser supports viewing PDF then it will open in a new tab otherwise it ll begin download.

Comment: I am able to view this on the popup problem is how do I close this with out user interference.

Comment: Please post your code we can't help much by guessing

Answer (score 0):

```
var win; win = window.open('" + vServletURL +
            "','_blank',\"height=300,width=200,scrollbars=no,status=no, resizable=no\");"+
            "setTimeout(function(){if(!win.closed)win.close();},5000);
```

To popup the pdf.. my servlet builds the pdf;

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();out.write(baos.toByteArray()); out.flush(); out.close();
```

were baos being ByteArrayOutputStream